# Session expired on refresh after login in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am putting the following in the config file:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';

$config['sess_expiration']      = 0;

$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;

$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;

$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;

$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';

$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;

$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;

$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 86400;
```

I am using the codeigniter framework.

In login page, I am storing the username in session, after login the session username is loading, once I refresh the page the name has gone.

What might be the problem? I extended the session expiry and everything but it is not working.

Comment: Refreshing the page (CTRL+F5 or other methods) will cause the script to be re-executed. Without seeing what that script does it is impossible to be sure, but it is likely your login page that is trashing the session. Post your login script or likely as not this question going to get closed as lacking in information

Comment: why is the sess_expiration is zero, it must be positive value as it is number of SECONDS you want the session to last.i believe this could be the issue because its not setting at all as sess_expiration  is zero

Comment: What CI version is used?

Answer (score 0):

Try these settings, following are working for me,

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 60*60*24;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

You have set `$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;` that means it wont last a second

and you have missed this one `$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;`

Answer (score 0):

I Run into with this problem before 
And I used  database for my session  so  when I  used this ,
I should set empty for `$config['sess_cookie_name']    = '';`

Now I think if u set

`$config['sess_table_name'] = '';`

Your problem solve .

This is  my code

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = '';
$config['sess_expiration']  = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']  = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```